# Pipe generated javascript via commandline

Tags: javascript, php, shell, pipe, phantomjs

We use [**PhantomJS**](http://phantomjs.org/) to create a screenshot of a webpage. It is run from the commandline, because for some reason [php-phantomjs](https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs) and [screen-master](https://github.com/microweber/screen/blob/master/shot.php) don't work on our server. The solution is to run the commandline script with a PHP `shell_exec()` command.

PhantomJS uses a javascript file which tells what to do, which page to load, and where to write the file. As multiple users will use this functionality, I need to pass a user ID or something onto the javascript file, so it can load a user specific page and save the screenshot with a user ID in the name.

One option is to generate the javascript by PHP, and then use that. Take the following javascript:

```
var id = 1234;
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = { width: 1024, height: 768 };
page.clipRect = { top: 0, left: 0, width: 1024, height: 768 };
page.open('http://test.local/screenshot.php?id='+id, function(status) {
  console.log("Status: " + status);
  if(status === "success") {
    page.render('/var/www/test/tmp/screenshot-'+id+'.png');
  }
  phantom.exit();
});
```

The shell command is like this:

```
/path/to/phantomjs /var/www/test/js/phantom.js
```

The variable `id` has value `1234`. This value is not fixed but changes per user. The javascript file is not dynamic, but can be generated using PHP. I could generate the javascript file, or just generate the script.

**Can I pipe this generated script (or file) to PhantomJS via the commandline?**

**What other options do I have that may work better to get this working?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want send command args to pj, you can do this like that:

```
 var system = require('system');
    var page = require('webpage').create();
    page.open(system.args[1], function () {
        page.paperSize = { format: 'A4', orientation: 'landscape'};
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            page.render(system.args[2]);
            phantom.exit();
        },300);
    });
```

And in php:

```
$cmd = 'phantomjs '.$path. 'render.js '.$html_tpl.' '. $image;
exec($cmd);
```